# typescript Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am calling `combineReducers` (`import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable'`) in `typescript` like this:

```
return combineReducers({
    byId,
    visibleIds
})(state, action)
```

but typescript complains this:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
```

so I see the type definition file:

```
declare module "redux-immutable" {
    export function combineReducers(reducers : Object): Object;
}
```

how can I call `combineReducer` correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type definition is wrong, this should work:

```
declare module "redux-immutable" {
    export function combineReducers(reducers : Object): Function;
}
```

Though the type definition is the official [Redux typings](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts) is:

```
function combineReducers<S>(reducers: ReducersMapObject): Reducer<S>;
```